# how to create a google chart in laravel from a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, google-visualization

Trying to get my head around this but lack of good documentation/examples is killing me.  The best example from which I modeled my approach is here:

> https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-line-chart-example-code-using-google-charts-apiexample.html

In my laravel web.php, I set route like this:

```
Route::get('/chart', 'ChartController@index');
```

Here is my ChartController.index code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Measurement;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\Chartjs\Chart;

class ChartController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        Log::debug('made it to ChartController.php');
        $tests = Measurement::where('test_id', '=', 49)
                    ->leftJoin('labs','lab_id','=','labs.id')
                    ->select('labs.dateEntered','value')
                    ->get();
        Log::debug("tests=" .$tests);

        $result[] = ['Date','Value'];
        foreach($tests as $key => $value) {
            $result[++$key] = [$value->dateEntered, (int)$value->value];
        }
        Log::debug("result=" .$result);
        return view('plot')
            ->with('tests',json_encode($result));
    }
}
```

Here is the plot.blade.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var tests = <?php echo $tests; ?>;
      console.log(tests);
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(tests);
        var options = {
          title: 'Laboratory Test Chart',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="linechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the log output:

> [2020-02-14 01:35:46] laravel.DEBUG: made it to ChartController.php
>   [2020-02-14 01:35:46] laravel.DEBUG: tests=[{"dateEntered":"2011-02-05
>   00:00:00","value":"117"},{"dateEntered":"2011-07-29
>   00:00:00","value":"69"},{"dateEntered":"2011-10-28
>   00:00:00","value":"125"},{"dateEntered":"2012-04-28
>   00:00:00","value":"84"},{"dateEntered":"1970-01-01
>   00:00:00","value":"95"},{"dateEntered":"2016-08-13
>   00:00:00","value":"189"},{"dateEntered":"2017-11-17
>   00:00:00","value":"195"},{"dateEntered":"1970-01-01
>   00:00:00","value":"127"},{"dateEntered":"1970-01-01
>   00:00:00","value":"127"}]

But that is as far as it gets.  It fails with "Array to string conversion" on line 47 which is this one:

```
Log::debug("result=" .$result);
```

It feels like I'm close but just can't get over this last obstacle.  Suggestions?

Comment: `Log::debug("result=" . json_encode($result)];`

Comment: Thank you Erich.  I didn't realize how picky the debug output was.  Added your suggestion and now it is working!

Comment: It actually didn't have anything to do with the debug output.  You were trying to concatenate an array onto the end of a string, which doesn't work unless you convert it to a string first.  `json_encode` is a handy way to do that.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  Been a while working in PHP.  Java has no such issues.

Comment: Ha!  Going from Laravel to regular PHP I often have the same frustrations.  :)